# Beta Testing with test flight if client have Individual enrolment

Tags: ios, testflight

I have built an app which client wants to be tested using Apple Test Flight. Client bought individual license, therefore he can not connect me as a team member, he can only add me in iTunes connect as an App Manager.

So is there a possibility to archive app on my computer and then upload it for the Test Flight, I mean can I do it instead of client or since client have an individual license only he needs to do it himself?

Comment: the best option allows remote access of your system to the client. Now ask client to log in your Application loader with his credential & upload the app. Once compelted logout from the account.

Answer (score 1):

I had the **same** situation and client didn't want to provide me his credentials. The only option was to connect to my mac using TeamViewer or ScreenHero and he could input the credentials once (without saving them in the browser).

Then I followed these **amazing** [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/distributing-ios-apps-with-itunes-connect--cms-21672).

After completing all the steps of the tutorial I logged out. Basically, everything was done in 1 session. Make sure you keep that account used since it may log you out due to being idle.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are an 'App Manager' the client must have provided you with the credentials.  You have limited access, but you CAN archive your app with App Manager role.  Please check this [User Roles](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW24) document by apple to get an idea about user roles.

What you have to do is, ask your client to send Certificates, Keys and Provision profiles which are needed to build the app.

For testing on the device - Developer certificate(.cer), Key (.p12) and password for the key, Development Provision Profile

For production purposes - Production certificate(.cer), Key (.p12) and password for the key, Production Provision Profile

Or else ask client to export Developer Profile (.developerprofile) from his machine.

Install these on you machine by double clicking and providing the received passwords where it’s needed.

Login to the Apple Developer Account with given user credentials. 
And archive using production certificates. Once the Organizer window prompted select ‘Upload to App Store’. Once you are asked to select the team select ‘use local signing assets’.  Once the process completed you will be able to upload it to the App Store.